# All email directed to 3rd party vendor except for one specific domain. How?

Tags: email

So we setup a site to site vpn tunnel with another company. We then proceeded to setup a DNS zone on each others dns servers and entered in each others Mail server name and IP, MX record and WWW record.  This allowed us to send emails to each others mail servers through the site to site vpn.

Now recently the other company started using MX Logic to scan all outbound and incoming mail.  So all outbound email is directed to MX Logic.

However we still want email between us to travel across the the Site to Site VPN tunnel.  How can we specify that to happen for just one domain not to be directed to MX Logic?

Stump on both ends and looking for help.

Comment: What is the MTA in use?

Comment: I am certain they are using SMTP, however I do not have access to the other companies servers.  They are not sure how to set this up to work, and I am trying to investigate and find a solution for it.

Comment: telnet to the smtp server on port 25 and see if the banner tells you anything

Answer (score 0):

**sendmail:** Add an entry in mailertable to specify an smtp server for the appropriate domain.

Answer (score 0):

With postfix, you can use a transport map to accomplish this.

The basic plan would be to create a file named `transport` in your `/etc/postfix` directory, and fill it with something like this:

```
otherguysdomain.com smtp:mailserver.otherguysdomain.com
```

Add this to your /`etc/postfix.main.conf`:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Compile the map like so:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

The reload postfix:

```
postfix reload
```

You can learn a little more about `transport` [here](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html).